# Server does not lookup www or other subdomains

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, server, cpanel

I have some problems, and I think that it's related to DNS Records.

I can't open my website by `www.` or access any sub-domain.

These are my DNS settings:

```
 example.de.        14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***  
 mail.example.de.   14400   IN  CNAME   example.de  
 www.example.de.    14400   IN  CNAME   example.de  
 ftp.example.de.    14400   IN  CNAME   example.de  
 *.example.de.      14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***   
 ns1.example.de.    14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***  
 ns2.example.de.    14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***
```

And when I do a DNS lookup, I get the following:

```
Type    Host        Class   TTL     Data
A       example.de  IN      21599   ip = **.***.***.***
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.earth.orderbox-dns.com
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.mars.orderbox-dns.com
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.mercury.orderbox-dns.com
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.venus.orderbox-dns.com
SOA     example.de  IN      7199    mname = irdns.mercury.orderbox-dns.com
                                    rname = example.mail.com
                                    serial = 2015081203
                                    refresh = 7200
                                    retry = 7200
                                    expire = 172800
                                    minimum-ttl = 38400
```

**`**.***.***.***`** is my server IP.

The problem is just on `.de`; I have used the same settings on my other domain, and everything is fine.

My server is Apache, and it has cPanel for management.

Comment: And if you do a DNS lookup on `www.example.de`?

Comment: @w3d just returns `A www.cleefchat.de IN 21599 ip = 173.193.105.244`

Comment: @w3d `173.193.105.244` is not my server ip, please help

Comment: You seem to have 2 `A` records for `example.com` pointing to different IP addresses? One of which is the IP address mentioned above. (?)

Comment: @w3d ohh yes, sometimes even i get two `A` record without `www.`!! what must i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have 2 `A` records for `example.com` pointing to very different IP addresses, one of which is the one that `www.example.com` resolves to (which is the wrong one). My guess is that it's picking the first one that it finds!?